# how can Tensor object add a new layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use googel wide&deep net,but it has some problem.

```
#Wide part
wide = Sequential()
wide.add(Dense(1, input_dim=X_train.shape[1]))

#Deep part, Wide and Deep are keras.engine.sequential.Sequential
deep = Sequential()
deep.add(Dense(input_dim=X_train.shape[1], output_dim=100, activation='relu'))
deep.add(Dense(input_dim=100, output_dim=32, activation='relu'))
deep.add(Dense(input_dim=32, output_dim=8))
deep.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
#merge the two part , and it changes to tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor  
model = Sequential()
model = layers.Concatenate()([wide.output, deep.output]) 

#I want to add a dense layer to get one result,but it doesn't work anymore <br>
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

[the net and red circle is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HghWe.png)
How can I deal with this problem, thanks very very much.

Comment: Are you trying to merge two layers?

Comment: Thank you. I add a picture, maybe it will help me describe the problem. I have already merged wide and deep part, now I need a dense layer to give the result..thank you very much